# Использование emoji  в заголовках, тексте и метках

Tags: обсуждение

Законно ли это?

️

Я понимаю что платформа позволяет, но как на это смотрят модераторы и другие участники?

Не будет ли это визуальным мусором, или это наоборот может быть неплохой возможностью донести что-либо лаконичнее чем словами?

Comment: Спасибо за наводку, теперь мои вопросы и ответы будут на 20% круче  

Comment: @iluxa1810 модератору ниже не понравилось. Готовьтесь к репрессиям.

Comment: кстати в метках оказалось нельзя

Comment: Побуду кэпом: законно, если это уместно.

Comment: Можно. Но учтите, я в них постоянно путаюсь

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Эмодзи, как и другие спецсимволы, можно использовать, если вопрос касается конкретного(-ых) эмодзи.

В вопросе об отображении/считывании конкретного символа нужно указать этот символ. В код-гольфе, посвященном эмодзи, это тоже может быть уместно. В вопросе по [Emojicode](https://www.emojicode.org/) без них не обойтись.

Пример, с английского Stack Overflow: [SQL Query Where Column = '' returning Emoji characters  and](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47551528)

Если эмодзи заменяют слова или используются чрезмерно, то они расцениваются как информационный шум  и должны быть удалены ♻️ или заменены ️. Впрочем, так же как и любое другое излишнее форматирование. <s>Кроме случаев когда получается уж [очень удачно.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454)</s>

Answer (score 17):

Мусор. Удалять/вырезать. Я это засилье emoji во все сферы вообще не одобряю. Можете кидать в меня тапками (:

Comment:  обувь для кидания в модератора в ассортименте

Comment: В целом согласен, эмодзи почти всегда оффтопик. А что насчет текстовых смайлов по типу Т_Т?

Comment: @trollingchar иногда можно, главное не переусердствовать   (¬‿¬ )

Comment: @Suvitruf = ) ну вот, символов не хватило