# Как лучше на мете называть вопросы?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, мета

#### Вступление

Недавно я написал [вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10560/%d0%a2%d1%8b-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc?cb=1) под названием:

> Ты троянская пони, троянская пони! ✨

Вопрос оценили, им заинтересовались и частично благодаря загадочно-шуточному названию.

#### Продолжение

Потом Kromster сказал, что это плохое название, что мол надо называть по сути и выкатил правку. Я откатил.
После небольшого обсуждения в комментариях пришли к названию:

> Ты троянская пони, троянская пони! ✨ (Как защититься от вопросов с вредоносным кодом?)

Comments:

> Добавил. Но мне кажется уже само название стоит того, чтобы не удержаться и зайти в него. И очень пятнично! – A K♦ 26 июн в 10:30
>
> @AK Эту штуку придумал andreymal. Мне тоже кажется прикольно!Спасибо за тег!!! ;) – Victor VosMottor thanks Monica 26 июн в 10:32
>
> @AK Now 26 Jun. 26 is double 13 ;) – Victor VosMottor thanks Monica 26 июн в 10:46
> 3
>
> На самом деле этот код безопасен, потому что современные версии rm просто выдадут ошибку it is dangerous to operate recursively on '/' – andreymal 26 июн в 10:49
>
> @andreymal Не важно... У кого-то может старый rm. Может быть другой, но похожий опасный вопрос. Обсудить все равно надо. И есть --no-preserve-root. – Victor VosMottor thanks Monica 26 июн в 10:56
>
> Давайте вопроса нормальные описательные названия, пожалуйста. – Kromster 26 июн в 11:19
> 2
>
> Название было весёлое, но правда, давайте оставим хорошее описательное и не будем устраивать войн правок, ладно? – A K♦ 26 июн в 11:28
> @AK Компромисс. – Victor VosMottor thanks Monica 26 июн в 11:29
> 1
>
> @Kromster Компромисс? (Пусть хотя бы сегодня в честь двойной пятницы*13тое повисит) – A K♦ 26 июн в 11:30
>
> Нет войне правок! - откатил автор - ок. Тревога модератору - пусть он рассудит ) Я лично против опошления ресурса и желтизны заголовков )

[Edits](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/10560/revisions)

Потом модераторы все же откатили название:

> Как защититься от вопросов с вредоносным кодом?

Hо не единогласно. Я сам не уверен, что лучше.

## Что я хочу обсудить

- Какие названия лучше: описательные или креативные?
- Когда что приемлемо?
- Имеет ли это вообще значение?

Community, let's talk!

Comment: Эх, любишь же ты тонну информации в вопрос загнать...

Comment: @Qwertiy долго этому учился...

Comment: Заголовок «[I want to delete the \[internet\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255169)» попадает под обе характеристики

Comment: @andreymal, пони - тоже под обе.

Comment: @Qwertiy Suvitruf не согласен ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @andreymal, его ответ вообще только про эмоджи - можно их выпилить, а про пони оставить.

Comment: Эмодзи выпилить, повтор/песнопение выпилить, уточнение в скобках оставить - вот и отлично все будет.

Comment: @Kromster всю отсылочку разломал :(

Comment: @Kromster ...вот и хрень будет.

Comment: Подобные вопросы должны быть именно что с привлекательно-информативными заголовками, т.е. текущий заголовок отлично подходит - Привлекателен (необычный, привлекает к вопросу), Информативен (понятно о чем он, привлекает к проблеме). Сами посмотрите какой резонанс вызвал.

Comment: @DaemonHK ага!!

Comment: Как же все на этом сайте строго. Даже вопрос на мете, который набрал много "плюсов" подвергается редакторской критике. Мне кажется, в текущей редакции вопрос прекрасно отражает содержание. Пусть даже с "пони". Не вижу ничего плохого в этом. Я считаю, что важнее - получить интерес и одобрение со стороны сообщества ru-stackoverflow, чем следовать строгим правилам оформления

Answer (score 5):

Уже были обсуждения этого. Последнее на моей памяти: [Использование emoji 🐟 в заголовках, тексте и метках](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9266/15479).

Юмор - это прекрасно, если он не вредит основной мысли. Конкретно в вопросе про вредоносный код упоминание пони и эмодзи - лишь шум, который отвлекает от основной идеи.

Не нужно так делать, чтобы "привлечь внимание".

1. Для привлечения внимания к вопросу нужно заголовок говорящий подбирать.
2. Если используются эмодзи только для привлечения внимания, тогда все авторы вопросы в итоге начнут так делать, что превратит Мету в пикабу.

Я как и раньше против использования бесполезное шума в заголовках.

Comment: Приведите пример заголовка для того вопроса, чтобы "если он не вредит основной мысли", и при этом какой-то интересный. Вряд ли придумаете, да и большинство наших вопросов (и моих, и любых других участников) вполне офицальные и "солидные". Почему не внести немного юмора? Тем более я в скобках пояснил о чем речь, да это и так легко догадаться.

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica "Как защититься от вопросов с вредоносным кодом?" - понятный всем заголовок.

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica `Тем более я в скобках пояснил о чем речь, да это и так легко догадаться` я вот по этим "пони" и эмодзи не понимаю, о чём вопрос.

Comment: Ну хорошо, но и что это единственный критерий для заголовка?

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica заголовок должен отражать суть вопроса. Это основное его предназначение.

Comment: Слово "троянский" отражает ИМХО.

Comment: Ладно, не спорю, подождем, кто еще какого мнения. В конце концов это спорный вопрос и решать его должно большинство.

Comment: Так обсуждается весь заголовок, а не только наличие в нём эмодзи. Можно удалить только эмодзи, а заголовок с пони оставить.

Comment: @Qwertiy а что упоминание пони привносит в вопрос?

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik, троянского коня с одновременной отсылкой к описываемому вопросу и намёком на какие-то мелкие гадости. Я вроде в своём ответе описал.

Answer (score 4):

На мой взгляд, интересные названия лучше, потому что они привлекают внимание к вопросу. Естественно, при этом они должны быть как-то связаны с темой.

Традиционно на сайтах сети использовались названия с каламбурами для обсуждения меток. Правда, enSO некоторое время назад поменял политику про метки, но остальные сайты по-прежнему используют более интересный вариант.

Так что если есть возможность сделать заголовок более интересным, то стоит ей воспользоваться.

---

В указанном случае "троянская пони" явно ассоциируется с троянским конём и понятно, что речь о том, чтобы тайно засунуть в сообщение зловредный код. На мой взгляд название про пони лучше.

Comment: `зловредный код` ? Может лучше "опасный" или "вредоносный"? Хотя так конечно образней.

Comment: Абсолютно согласен!

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica, почему-то я привык именно к сочетанию "зловредный код", хотя "вредоносный" тоже можно. А вот "опасный" - это не то - `chmod 777` тоже опасный, sql-инъекции опасны, но мы ж говорим о другого рода опасностях, причём тайных.

Comment: ну да..........

Comment: И по поводу "вредоносный" vs "зловредный" - вредоносный может быть ответом на вопрос, например "как удалить все данные с диска, чтобы их невозможно было восстановить?" - вопрос корректен, а код из ответа в общем-то можно считать вредоносным, но в таком сочетании это не плохо, а "зловредный" выражает именно намерение автора сообщения.

Comment: Cогласен ......

Answer (score 3):

## IMO:

В написание вопроса на мете есть доля творчества. Интересные названия привлекают людей:

> Я на этот вопрос попал именно из-за названия. Точнее из-за той комбинации которая была на момент написания: "Ты троянская пони, троянская пони! ✨ (Как защититься от вопросов с вредоносным кодом?)".

Если по названию вот уж прям никак нельзя понять о чем речь можно сделать микс креативного и описательного или просто открыть вопрос ;)

Comment: Вот давайте сейчас всем вопросам будем давать "привлекательные названия" и пускай все вопросы открывают и смотрят о чем там внутри дело. Не забывайте, название вопроса должно быть его выжимкой и отражать содержимое, иначе оно по сути бесполезно.

Comment: @Kormster Ну тогда названия книг неинформативны и бессмысленны. Будем на обложке книги пересказывать сюжет.

Comment: И много вы таких серьезных книг видели, "Ах брюква моя брюква, %)!!" про архитектуру ПО на Скале? ))

Comment: @Kromster Я говорю про художественные.

Comment: Вот тут вы видимо и не заблуждаетесь. StackOverflow не площадка для художественных тем, мемчиков, соцпросов, конкурсов талантов и т.п. SO это практический полезный прикладной сборник по программированию и смежным темам.

Comment: @Kromster `мемчиков` ? [Are you sure?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta)

Comment: То что на SO рождаются собственные мемы и попадают в анналы - замечательно. Но они - byproduct функционирования, а не цель ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Вы забываете главное - StackOverflow это база знаний, а не социальная сеть (да, и Мета тоже!). Название вопроса должно быть понятным и информативным. Если удается сочетать его с шуткой без потери смысла - хорошо (см. вопросы по меткам).

В вашем конкретном случае, название было неинформативно, да еще и с ненужными эмодзи, которые только зря отвлекают.

Comment: Обоснуй неинформативность.

Comment: @Qwertiy по-моему это очевидно, так же как "раскладывание вишни по чернозему" очень неиформативная метафора к "черно-красным деревьям".

Answer (score 1):

Креативные заголовки нужны для того, чтобы зацепить читателя и повысить вероятность прочтения. То есть, по сути своей, ***вопросам*** на обычном stackoverflow они не нужны ибо заголовки там необходимы для краткого пересказа всего текста.

На мете тоже эти заголовки не подходят всем вопросам. Я думаю креативность уместна в том случае, если о вопросе можно сказать, что это статья с призывом поделиться своим мнением. Ибо как я уже говорил раньше, эта креативность нужна чтобы текст **читали**.

Разберем на двух примерах из Меты.

Вопрос: какой рекорд снятия репутации (не помню формулировку).

В данном случае не нужен яркий заголовок. Это просто вопрос, в котором отсутствует какое-либо рассуждение. Заголовок здесь предназначен для описания сути вопроса.

Вопрос: Ты троянская пони, троянская пони! ✨ (Как защититься от вопросов с вредоносным кодом?)

Здесь креативность уже более подходит из-за структуры вопроса, большого количества информации, а также присутствия некоего "рассуждения".

Надеюсь, мое мнение было вам понятно: Креативность должна быть в меру и не везде.

Comment: Господа минусующие, а в чем собственно я неправ? Поделитесь своим мнением, если не трудно.

Comment: Минус на мете обычно выражает явное несогласие. Не обращайте внимания.

Comment: А что поделать? На SO мало кто объясняет свои минусы...

Comment: @Shift Один из минусов мой. И поставил я его, потому что не согласен с Вашей позицией (в отличие от [другой](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/10587/339283)). В этом и есть смысл голосования на мете.

Comment: Ок, я понял Вашу точку зрения. Спасибо за то, что поделились ей.